# How can I add a simple post-build action to Android Studio's Gradle?

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

With Eclipse, I had a post build event that zipped up the APK and the map file from DexGuard.  The resulting zip was more convenient to move to my production server than having to move the two files individually.

How can I add this zip action to Android Studio's Gradle?

Is there a simple way to do this?  I'd rather not have to become a Gradle programmer just to zip two files together.

Comment: This could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636905/gradle-copy-file-after-its-generation