# How can I improve this task which copies the output APK from an Android project to a new folder?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So I want to create a post-build hook which copies the compiled APK file to a new folder and give it a name which includes the version code. This is what I've got so far:

```
task copyToPublishFolderDebug(type: Copy, dependsOn: assembleDebug ) {
    def targetFile = "MyApp-debug-" + android.defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk"
    from ('build/outputs/apk/MyApp-debug.apk') {
        rename 'MyApp-debug.apk', targetFileName
    }
    into '../build/publish/' 
}
assembleDebug.finalizedBy copyToPublishFolderDebug
```

This works but I think it can improved

- The ideal solution would not be to hard-code the input file name but to pipe the output from `assembleDebug` to this task. (Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30637190/507339) The problem is that `assembleDebug` does not have any output. `zipalignDebug` does however, but the task does not exist in the evaluation phase so writing `from zipalignDebug` does not compile. Any way to work around this? Can I define tasks in the `afterEvalate`-phase?
- I have to copy-paste this task to a 90% identical one for the release build (and any other build types I've created). Any way to in a simple way DRY that thing up?

**edit**: Misunderstood problem #1, thought it was a file not a directory. Copying is done correctly except it creates a folder and does not rename

**edit2**: Found out how to rename so that's no longer an issue

Comment: how does the selected answer solve your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could use external properties:

```
ext.output = "Initial Value"

task firstTask() << {
    output = "Output";
}

task secondTask(dependsOn: firstTask) << {
    println output;
}
```

Will yield:
Output

If you have multiple assemble-type tasks and each one sets 'output' accordingly, then your duplication is no longer multiple tasks but multiple set statements.