# Can't use variable defined in gradle.properties

Tags: java, gradle

I am new to Gradle and am trying to create a configurable variable via the gradle.properties file.

To do this, I have created a `gradle.properties` file at the root of my project, and defined a build directory like this:

```
buildDir="~/my/custom/build/directory"
```

In my `build.gradle` file I have referenced the variable like this:

```
libsDirName = buildDir
```

This does not work. If I swap `buildDir` for the string in `gradle.properties` it builds to the correct location. Why is this happening?

Here is the complete build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

// This fails
libsDirName = buildDir

// This builds correctly
libsDirName = "~/my/custom/build/directory"

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: To get only jar file to a specific directory.**

I hope you can't restrict creating tmp, resources during gradle build.
So The idea is to copy a jar file to a specific directory once the gradle build success.

I suggest referring this link to copy jar.

[gradle - copy file after its generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636905/gradle-copy-file-after-its-generation)

You change

```
buildDir="~/my/custom/build/directory"
```

to

```
buildDir=~/my/custom/build/directory
```

and try..

Also, can you add `println buildDir` in *build.gradle* file and check what it prints.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you declare and access a variable in Gradle file. refer below :

Below is how you declare a variable

```
def buildDir = "~/my/custom/build/directory"
```

Below is how you use its value

```
libsDirName = "${buildDir}"
```

Let me know if you face any issue. Happy Coding :)

Comment: The quotations marks around the variable are totally unnecessary as are the braces and dollar sign `libsDirName = buildDir` is fine. You only need to do it your way if you are doing string interpolation. You would only need the braces if you are evaluating an expression.